# springframework website changed - http://www.springframework.org/beans/ gone?

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

My application references the spring beans schema like so:

```
http://www.springframework.org/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

or

```
http://www.springframework.org/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
```

etc

My application is failing because this resource is no longer there.  Starting today.  Is this intended deprecation or something?

My application is down because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (reply) , I'm getting a timeout (522) when it try to curl the resource.

```
Error 522 Ray ID: 4c236b3d7adcb7e9 • 2019-04-04 12:52:51 UTC
```

Connection timed out

However I'm able to access the resource at 
https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd

Comment: Exactly.  My production app is no longer functional because of this.  Should this be like this?

Comment: Hum I have no idea... but did you try to change the reference in your app with the link I provided  ?

Comment: Yes, that solves it but this is a live client-server system so I have to update all my users.  I am trying to understand if this was a planned change or what.  If you search spring-beans-3.2.xsd on google the first item that comes up is still the old link.

Comment: As of today, the resources seem to be accessible, It was surely a server issue on pivotal side...  Oddly enough, I don't see any trace of reported issues on their side. Glad I could help a bit

Comment: Makes me wonder if I should be storing these resources in some local off line location to avoid this.  Although this is the only time I have seen this happen in at least 5 years.